# OP no longer highlighted

Tags: bug, status-completed

I have noticed that the OP's name as it appears when they write an answer or make a comment is no longer highlighted differently from everyone else answering/commenting.

[Here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18523/are-there-any-scriptural-sources-that-hashem-loves-each-jew-individually?rq=1) is an example of a comment not highlighted:

[image]

[Here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/53117/is-an-eishet-yefat-toar-beautiful-physically-or-spiritually?rq=1) is an example of an answer not highlighted:

[image]

Scimonster is the OP.

They used to be, until very recently, highlighted with a grey background.

Comment: On my devices, the OP's name is highlighted orange.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, [this has been pointed out on Meta Stack Exchange](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/393956). I recommend you keep an eye out over there for status updates.

Comment: ok, please delete the question if you see fit

Comment: If poss, please delete as the problem is fixed